# Achar elemento usando Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Olá,
Eu estou tentando cliclar em um elemento usando webdriver com pythone selenium

O elemento :

```
<a class="ppm_button_menu_item" alt="Exportar para CSV" href="javascript:clarity.uitk.exportToFile( 'npt.gridCsvExport&amp;RhXm0r7tSeUqEr=true&amp;odf_view=projectCreate.subObjList.cop_prj_statusrpt&amp;odf_code=project&amp;parentObjectCode=project&amp;id=5180135&amp;odf_concrete_parent_object_code=project&amp;object=cop_prj_statusrpt&amp;view_code=cop_prj_statusrptList&amp;componentId=odf&amp;portlet_id=projmgr.projectProperties&amp;portlet_instance_id=cop_prj_statusrptList&amp;portlet_instance_type=SYSTEM&amp;page_id=projmgr.projectProperties', '25000', 'cop_prj_statusrptList')" onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;"> button1 </a>
```

O x.path do elemento:

```
//*[@id="d560c4a2-e016-41f9-b56b-697b8fb4f5e6"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]/span[2]/a[3]
The problem is; This id number is auto generated and everytime the page is reload its change, so I cant use in the code.
```

o elemento que o ID do código anterior se refere é o seguinte:

```
<form name="page" method="POST" id="d560c4a2-e016-41f9-b56b-697b8fb4f5e6" autocomplete="off" type="form" action="nu" onsubmit="return false;"><input type="hidden" name="scenarioId" value=""><div class="ppm_filter_section" aria-expanded="false">
```

Eu tentei fazer o python achar o botão desse jeito:

```
campo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@name="page"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]/span[2]/a[3]')
campo.click()
```

Eu não sei mais o que fazer :(

Comment: existem outras tags `form`ou apenas essa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, primeiramente gostaria de saber se a página em questão é pública, caso for e queira compartilhar poderíamos inspecionar melhor o que está acontecendo.

Mas vou deixar uma solução que já utilizei muito, um recurso em javascript que você poderá executar via selenium.

partindo do suposto que você tenha conhecimento em javascript básico, abra o navegador na página em que está a tag e abra o console de desenvolvedor do google chrome e faça uma busca por tag conforme:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
```

se na página existir mais que uma tag do tipo "a", sugiro que vá alterando o valor inicial de zero para: "('a')[1]", "('a')[2]", "('a')[3]" até encontrar a posição do elemento que você deseja (se fizer isso pelo console do google chrome ele vai destacar qual objeto está se referindo).

depois que encontrar qual é a posição do elemento entre os outros da mesma tag é só adicionar um .click() ao final:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
```

pressionando enter deverá acontecer a ação de um clique, e se isso funcionar poderá incluir isso em seu código assim:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()')
```

sem acesso a página para efetuar um teste esta é a única solução que eu posso oferecer, peço que teste e reporte o resultado.